# How to get a specific button component

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

I'd like Unity to get a specific button with:

```
GetComponent<Button>().interactable
```

But how do I get a specific button with a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, `someObject.GetComponent` gets a component attached to `someObject`.

If you don't lead with a specific object to look in, and just type `GetComponent` on its own, it refers to "this" object: the same one that the component running the script you're writing is attached to.

The best way to reference a specific button (or any other component) is to expose it as a member variable at the top of your class, outside of any methods:

```
public Button buttonIWantToUse;
```

This will create a slot in the Inspector where you can assign a reference to the button directly, with no searching at runtime.

If searching can't be avoided in your case, you can look up an object with a specific name in the active scene with:

```
var soughtObject = GameObject.Find("Some Name");
var buttonOnSoughtObject = soughtObject.GetComponent<Button>();
```

But I recommend avoiding looking up objects by name. It's not as fast or reliable as storing a reference, and it's easy to get  [downright baffling bugs](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/672973048899702784) that way.

Comment: Thanks for this, and i just realised i could use this to fix some other bugs